# How to save instances using Eucalyptus (Typica API)

Tags: cloud, instance, kvm, eucalyptus, java

I am a newbie to clouds and Eucalyptus, I used [Typica Java API](http://code.google.com/p/typica/), it has method

> [createImage](http://typica.s3.amazonaws.com/com/xerox/amazonws/ec2/Jec2.html#createImage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)(instance_id, new_image_name)

but it fails and the error isn't shown, does Euclyptus support this feature?

- Problem 1: After opening an
  image(Windows or Ubuntu), I want to
  install applications on the instance
  and then save the instance as new
  image.
- Problem 2: Is it possible to
  save also the context of
  instance(opened applications),
  something like hibernate? so I can
  restore the instance in its state.

Does Eucalyptus has solutions to these problems? **a detailed steps or commands will be highly appreciated.**

Installation information: 
Eucalyptus version:2.2, UEC package, Hypervisor type:KVM

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure exactly what that Typica API call does, but I can provide some information about Eucalyptus and the ability to save instances. First of all, Eucalyptus doesn't provide a solution to Problem #2 today. That's not something that's supported by the Amazon API so we don't provide it yet. Perhaps someday.

Problem #1 is easier to solve. There is an operation called "rebundling" that you can use to take an running instance in your cloud, and bundle up all of the changes to the root filesystem back into a new Eucalyptus Machine Image (EMI). Eucalyptus has more information about [bundling images](http://open.eucalyptus.com/participate/wiki/bundling-images).

One more thing I should mention. In the upcoming release of Eucalyptus 3 later this fall, we will support a new instance type which is backed by an EBS volume. This is like Amazon EC2's "Boot from EBS" support where you can have a persistent root filesystem.

Hope this helps!

-Tim